# Лицензия qt.Написание программы на бесплатном qt для продажи незаконно?

Tags: c++, qt, gui, ui, лицензирование

После 3-4(-ёх) дневных попыток найти **бесплатный** инструмент конструирования GUI windows окон для c++.(обуздать visual windows forms например)Решил всё-же попробовать qt но загвоздка в том ,что он вроде как раз *не бесплатный*.(Как я понял продавать программы написанные на нём можно только купив лицензию qt)Это так?Кто нибудь может простым языком объяснить как работает лицензия qt, и или предложить альтернативный вариант?

Comment: Community-версии ведь являются бесплатными и лицензионными, разве нет?

Comment: Если публиковать исходники - то всё ок, GPL V3. Подробнее - [раздел про open source](https://www.qt.io/faq/). Ещё можете на [этой странице](https://www.qt.io/qt-training/#modal-qt-essentials) скачать (внизу кнопка `Download`) материалы для обучения, там есть презентация в которой более менее понятно написано про опции различных лицензий, с картинками что к какой лицензии относится

Comment: @vegerov не только GPL, но и LGPL : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/lgpl.html поэтому достаточно не вносить изменения в исходники Qt, и не линковать их статически. Тогда можно использовать Qt, даже в комерческих продуктах, без публикации исходников.

Comment: Простым языком даже сами представители Digia отказываются объяснять, как правильно использовать LGPL, советуют нанять юриста

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/331166

Comment: Ещё имейте ввиду, что если вы пишете для использования только внутри компании, то можете использовать GPL и не предоставлять исходники

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать Qt для своего продукта, и вам не нужно делиться исходным кодом, но вам нужно использовать динамическую линковку на библиотеки, которые находятся под лицензией LGPL.

А если всё-таки без статической линковки не обойтись, то вы можете просто распространять свои объектные файлы (не исходный код), и все будет в порядке.

Comment: Компоновка программы со статическим Qt идет так долго, что врагу не пожелаешь, в районе минуты может идти

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Это из-за того, что помимо ваших исходников необходимо ещё скомпилировать классы Qt которые вы включили в свой проект. А при динамической линковки код классов Qt уже скомпилирован за Вас в dll. Динамическая линковка полезна, когда нужно получить один exe без dll рядом, например для установщика.